# renderToNodeStream [object Object] server-side-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream(
      <Html
        helmet={Helmet.renderStatic()}
        window={{
          __STATE__: ctx.store.getState()
        }}
        css={css}
        scripts={scripts}
        locale={ctx.locale}
        url={ctx.request.url}
        dynamicData={dynamicData}
      >
        {components}
      </Html>
    )
```

[image]

I can't find what is the reason of this issue . I want to switch to `renderToNodeStream` but it works in little bit different way then `renderToStaticMarkup` and I can't find out it .

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I’m having same issue now. On initial load it shows object object on the browser and then renders actual page. It would be great if you have solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the store as a json object to the html tag. You may use JSON.stringify and append the store like this,

```
`window={{
    __STATE__: JSON.Stringify(ctx.store.getState())
}}`
```

If the store contains any malicious script tag rendered from the API response, that would also get executed within the HTML. To avoid this cross-site scripting(XSS), I would highly recommend importing the `serialize` (`serialize-javascript`) package and use it like this.

```
`window={{
   __STATE__: serialize(ctx.store.getState())
}}`
```

Serialize will make sure the HTML characters and JavaScript line terminators are escaped automatically.